# c - memcopy for embedded system

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel

I just implemented my `memcpy` function without any previous lookup.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void * copy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num )
{
    if ((destination != NULL) && (source != NULL))
    {
        unsigned int *dst = destination;
        const unsigned int *src = source;
        
        unsigned int blocks = num/sizeof(unsigned int);
        unsigned int left = num%sizeof(unsigned int);
        
        while(blocks--){
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
        
        if (left){
            unsigned char *cdst = (unsigned char *)dst;
            const unsigned char *csrc = (const unsigned char *)src;
            
            while(left--)
                *cdst++ = *csrc++;
        }
        
    }
    
    return destination;
}
```

When looking at other memcpy implementations I find some differences:

1. unaligned address not handled
2. use of **long** instead **unsigned int**

Now what I didn't understand is point number 2. As far I know **int** will always be CPU WORD size i.e for 16bit it will be 2bytes and 32bit it will be 4bytes. But for long it must be 32bit minimum.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We review working code and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. We don't explain code or usage so both points 1 and 2 are borderline off-topic. We will review the `memcpy` function you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

**Alignment**

`unsigned int *dst = destination;` fails when `destination` is not aligned for `unsigned`.  Same for `src`. (OP seems be somewhat aware of this given "unaligned address not handled")

**Aliasing**

Possible strict aliasing violation.  See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98702/2410359)

**Fails when buffers overlap**

Without `restrict`, buffer may overlap and code does not well handle overlaps in both directions.

Recommend to use `restrict` like `memcpy()`.

```
void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);
```

**CPU WORD size**

"I know int will always be CPU WORD size" discounts 8-bits CPUs (common in embedded code).  On those, an `int` is at least 16-bit, not 8-bit.

The low-level copy size is typically related to the CPU word size, but much of this is implementation dependent.

Usually `unsigned` is good or best, but one would need to profile the implementation to know for sure.

**Minor: Unneeded code**

Test of `left` not unneeded as later `while(left--)` does the job.

```
// if (left)
```

**`NULL` Testing**

Common to *not* test for null-ness.  `memcpy()` is not require to do so, nor is it required to not test `NULL`.  What should be done depends on overall coding goals, so it is up to you.

Comment: The strict aliasing remark means that a library memcpy can never be compiled with standard compliant settings. The whole rule about effective type even points at memcpy, so that one can obviously not be applied to memcpy's internals.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `size_t` consistently

Since `num` is of type `size_t`, make sure you use this for all other sizes, counts and indices related to this.

## Unnecessary `if(left)`

It is not necessary to check for `left` being non-zero, the `while()` loop inside the `if`-block will perform that check as well.

## Don't check for `NULL` pointers

I would avoid the checks for `NULL` pointers. It should be up to the caller to ensure valid parameters are passed to your function. If you are worried about this, I recommend using `assert()` statements instead:

```
void *copy(void *destination, const void *source, size_t num)
{
    assert(destination != NULL);
    assert(source != NULL);
    ...
}
```

This way, a proper error message will be printed in debug builds. In release builds (with `-DNDEBUG`), the `assert()` statements will not do anything. If a `NULL`-pointer is passed, the program will get a segmentation fault. That's arguably better than this function silently ignoring the problem, as that can lead to the program continuing to run with possibly worse consequences.

## Unaligned addresses

Indeed you are not handling pointers that are not aligned to `int`'s requirements. This means that if you use this function on a CPU architecture that does not allow unaligned access, your program will probably crash with a bus error or something similar.

## Word size

It's hard to say what the best way to copy a large block of memory is. On some CPUs, an `int` might be the perfect size, but on others it might not. Try using a `long` or even a `long long`, and measure the time it takes on your machine. Remember that on other machines the results might be different.

On x86, using SSE or AVX registers might be even more efficient than using a regular integer, but some CPUs also have special instructions to handle copying large amounts of data, regardless of register size. However, if you want your code to be portable you probably shouldn't use these techniques.

Comment: `long` or `long long` will make the code extremely slow on low-end embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin Why? The only reason I can think of is you have a register-starved CPU, and the compiler doesn't optimize the copy and spills to temporary storage unnecessarily. Otherwise, the compiler would have to generate multiple load instructions, but that's actually perfectly fine here, because basically that's just equivalent to a bit of loop unrolling.

Comment: Because `long` is at least 32 bit and if used on a CPU with less than 32 bits data instructions, you'll get slow code. In case of 8-bit CPU, you will get _very_ slow code. And yes, those are typically "register-starved" in general, so you can end up using the stack as a go-between.

Comment: I tried this on godbolt (see https://godbolt.org/z/qxcrT7). GCC generates quite efficient code for the MSP430 and Atmel processors, but those have lots of registers. However, the code generted for the MOS6502 by cc65 look terrible (https://godbolt.org/z/8EM5na), both for the `long int` and `char` version.

Comment: The AVR code looks rather terrible too. Should look about as bad on PIC, HC08, STM8, 8051, Z80 and others. Most things called MSP430 are 16 bitters, so I'd expect those to fare much better.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this function is quite naively written to the point where you would be much better off with a plain byte-by-byte loop:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  src[i] = dst[i];
}
```

Benchmark and disassemble! If you can't beat the above performance with your own version, then you shouldn't be writing your own version.

- As pointed out by other reviews, you have a major bug in the form of misaligned access at the beginning of the copy, you only seem to handle misalignment at the end.
- There is also strict aliasing violations. In fact strict aliasing means that `memcpy` cannot be efficiently implemented in standard C - you must compile with something like `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing` or the compiler might go haywire. Many of the traditional embedded systems compiles don't abuse strict aliasing, but gcc has a history of doing so and it is getting increasingly popular.
- `restrict` qualifying the pointers will help fixing pointer aliasing hiccups and maybe optimize the code a tiny bit. This is standard lib memcpy:

  ```
    void *memcpy(void * restrict s1,
                 const void * restrict s2,
                 size_t n);
  ```
- Rolling out your own `memcpy` probably means it should be `static inline` and placed in a header, or otherwise it will by definition always be much slower than standard lib one.
- You need to minimize the amount of branches. The only branches that should exist in this function if any are the ones correcting for misaligned addresses in the beginning and the end of the data. Branches are very bad since they are likely the major bottlenecks here - if the CPU can't utilize data and instruction cache, then the whole algorithm is pointless since it is then almost certainly far worse than the previously mentioned for loop, at least on all high end CPUs. Even on mid- to low-end CPUs with no cache have instruction pipelining and might benefit from no branches.

  In particular the checks against NULL are just pointless bloat that shouldn't exist in a library function but get carried out by the caller, if at all needed.
- `unsigned int` is not guaranteed to be the fastest aligned type supported - it is true on 16 to 32 bit systems but not on 64 bit systems. The correct type to use in this case for maximum portability is `uint_fast16_t`. That one covers all systems with alignment requirements from 16 to 64 bit systems.

  However, 16 bit systems with alignment requirements are somewhat rare, I think a few oddball ones have it, but many 16 bitters don't, so consider if you actually need portability to those that do. Otherwise `uint_fast32_t` would work. Similarly, portability to 64 bitters might be irrelevant if you only target embedded systems.

  **IMPORTANT:** Most 8 and 16 bit systems have no alignment requirements and there's no obvious benefit of doing 16 bit word-sized copies on 8 bit systems. On such systems, these kind of "aligned chunk" memcpy implementations are just slow bloat - a plain byte-by-byte `for` loop would be much faster there. If you mean to target such systems, you will have to roll out a completely different implementation.
- Avoid `/` and `%` unless you have reason to believe that the compile can optimize them away. Division is very CPU-intense particularly on low-end systems. In this case you shouldn't need it, the "number of chunks" calculation isn't adding anything meaningful information for the algorithm. This is a typical case of "write code so that the programmer understands what's going on", which is normally a good thing, but not when writing library quality code. Instead simply check for the end address when iterating.
- `copy` is a bad function name since various library functions with that name have existed over the years.
- Don't include library headers that you don't use.